# How to Test Next.js's getServerSideProps with jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, next.js

I would like to run tests with Jest and Enzyme on Next.js's  `getServerSideProps` function. The function looks like the following:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context?.params?.id;
  const businessName = getBusinessName(id);
  return {
    props: {
      businessName: response.data?.name,
      businessID: id,
    },
  };
};
```

However since I'm using the `context` parameter in my function I need to pass a context into my test. My test right now looks like:

```
it("check on good case", () => {
    const value = getServerSideProps(/*I'm not sure what to put here*/);
    expect(value).toEqual({props: {businessName: "Name", businessID: "fjdks"}})
  });
```

My question is what do I pass into the parameter for context. I know it needs to be of type: `GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>`. But I'm not sure how to create that type. What can I pass into the function that also allows me to add an `id` value in the params as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resort to type casting when passing the `context` object to `getServerSideProps` in your test.

```js
it("check on good case", () => {
    const context = {
        params: { id: "fjdks" } as ParsedUrlQuery
    };
    const value = getServerSideProps(context as GetServerSidePropsContext);
    expect(value).toEqual({props: {businessName: "Name", businessID: "fjdks"}});
});
```

Comment: Not sure what version of TS this was for, but this definitely does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me, I am using next `13.1.5`, react `18.2.0`, typescript `4.9.4`, and jest `28.1.0`.

Here are the types that work for me:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';
import HomePage, { HomePageProps, getServerSideProps } from '../src/pages/index';

describe('Jest Snapshot testing suite', () => {
  it('Matches DOM Snapshot', async () => {
    const context = {
      params: { } as ParsedUrlQuery
    };

    const { props } = (await getServerSideProps(context as GetServerSidePropsContext)) as { props: HomePageProps};
    const { container } = render(HomePage(props));
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

With the following page exports:

```js
export type HomePageProps = { ... }

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<HomePageProps> = async () => { ... }

function HomePage(props: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>): any { ... }

export default HomePage;
```